# Browserify, react, and the conditional operator

Tags: reactjs, babelify

I cannot get `browserify` to compile a react file in which I'm trying to use a conditional to render.

The render function:

```
render() {
    const hasObjects = this.state.objects.length === 0 ? false : true;
    return {hasObjects ? (<p> Objects </p>) : (<p>No objects are available.</p>)};   
}
```

When I try to compile with `browserify`, I get the following error.

```
SyntaxError: ~/Projects/Project/src/index.js: Unexpected token, expected , (26:27)
  24 |     render() {
  25 |         const hasObjects = true;
 >26 |         return {hasObjects ? (<p> Objects </p>) : (<p>No objects are available.</p>)}
     |                            ^
  27 |     }
  28 |
```

I compile with `browserify src/index.js -o static/js/bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets [ env react ] ]`

and my .bablerc is:

```
{
     "plugins": [
         "react-html-attrs",
     ]
}
```

The documentation for react indicates that the conditional is a valid option for conditional rendering so I assume that this is a `browserify` issue. What option can I set to compile this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to wrap your expression in `{...}`, that is only required when passing an expression as a child in JSX. When you leave the braces there, JavaScript thinks you are returning an object.

Just remove the braces:

```
render() {
  const hasObjects = true;
  return hasObjects ? (<p> Objects </p>) : (<p>No objects are available</p>);
}
```

Comment: Alas, this is correct. After reviewing the documentation, the conditional that they had used was already inside of a div so I thought it was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

No need to wrap your expression in {...}
You might change your code to this:

`render() {
  const hasObjects = true;
  return hasObjects ? (<p> Objects </p>) : (<p>No objects are available</p>);
}`
This will work.